# Widnows registry - add detection for custom text in Outlook and open it in browser (like hyperlink)

Tags: windows, url, hyperlink, outlook, registry

I've been trying to find some way how to tweak the Windows registry to detect custom text in Outlook email bodies and use it as hyperlinks.

For example, if text "**CID:123456**" is used in an email body, it will be automatically detected and transformed into the following hyperlink and therefore opened in a default browser:

```
https://domain.com/cgi-bin/wwwcompas?prodid=123456&dformat=pdf
```

Any hints how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything rather thank just asking for a boilerplate solution?